# Role Based Authorization in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to secure checkbox in Reactjs to only authorized users with following method but problem is that if someone want can change state from false to true in dev tool and bypass security. the checkbox is in table having more than 100s of rows, for every row there is a checkbox. at the moment I check against the state of isAuthorized, if false I disable checkbox and it is working fine but can be changed in Dev tool. I also tried by calling a function for every table row to check API if authorized but problem is there is 100s of calls to API for every row  grateful for any suggestion to help me with this problem. much appreciated. PS. I checked google and all information is about route security and couldn't find anything relate to my problem.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const WorkList = (props) => {

  const [isAuthorized, setIsAuthorized] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        EMPID: "2514",
      }),
    };
    fetch(
      `https://api......`,
      requestOptions
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJSON) => {
        setIsAuthorized(responseJSON);
      });
  }, []);


  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Map Data In Table//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    return (
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Done </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {items.map((item) => (
                <tr key={item.Name}>
                  <td>{item.IsDone}</td>
                  <td>
                    {isAuthorized ? (<input type="checkbox" />) :
                     (<input type="checkbox" disabled />)}
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
    );
};

export default WorkList;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client side validation of user input is necessary but will never be sufficient. You should always check user input on the server-side as well. Your issue is one of the example as to why it is not sufficient.

Sadly there is nothing you can do to prevent it. Someone with malicious intent will always be able to counteract the mesures you take on the client side.

You should validate that the user is authorized to make the change on the server.

> However, client-side validation should not be considered an exhaustive
> security measure! Your apps should always perform security checks on
> any form-submitted data on the server-side as well as the client-side,
> because client-side validation is too easy to bypass, so malicious
> users can still easily send bad data through to your server.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

Here are a few links if you want to learn more about authorization token and JWT:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization

https://jwt.io

Comment: Thank you, now I added another security check in handleComplete() even if the user try to change state to true but it will fail.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you shouldn't add another security check in your react app. I'm saying you should check on the server that the user was authorized to make the changed before saving them in your database. You should try and learn about authorization and authentification tokens and JWT. I added links in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I added server side check too. I put in React as well with API call just to alert user that you are not authorized.

Answer (score 0):

+1 what SamiElk commented, but outside of the fact that you should validate this input on both the client and server side, a cleaner way to do it would be to retrieve the authorization status of the user in a parent component, and pass it down to this component here as a prop, instead of initializing it as state. Furthermore, if you're running a production build of React on your application (as you should be, since it trims out the irrelevant developer and debugging functionality), then they can't use the React devtools directly to change the state's value.

Comment: I agree with the fact that it would be harder to use React devtool. However with tools like burp suite or even postman it is easy to send unvalidated data to the api endpoints.

Comment: Oh yeah no, as I stated first server side validation was necessary regardless, but client side UI/UX is still important to get the authorization and display available actions properly. I wasn't trying to imply since they couldn't use devtools directly that it was secure, just that the devtools concern was a non-issue on production react.

Comment: Thank you, I think it is also good idea to send via props. but I am wondering if props is also vulnerable same as state and can be attacked in middle way.

Comment: As SamiElk pointed out, anything on the **client** side can be changed by the client, I was only pointing out that it would be a cleaner implementation of this and could be used elsewhere in the application as well if hoisted higher in the hierarchy.